# can I put a map inside an element? - Cannot add a map as a child of a constructed element

Tags: xslt-3.0

and can I match on it?

I'm creating an intermediary document, and whilst I'd usually do that in terms of elements/attributes, its quite convenient for me to do it as a map, but saxon complains

```
Cannot add a map as a child of a constructed element
```

(I thought it would simply 'serialise' as some sort of xml structure)

```
<xsl:variable name="foo">
    <foo>
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'bar'" select="'wibble'"/>
        </xsl:map>
    </foo>
</xsl:variable>
```

maybe its not that surprising, (though you can put an element in a map).

So if I flip the whole intermediary structure into a map, then how do I apply-templates/match on a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="map1" select="map { 'bar' : 'wibble' }"/>` and if you need it use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="$map1"/>` and e.g. `<xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(xs:string, xs:string)]">..</xsl:template>`.

In terms of navigating/matching maps there is a lack of ancestor navigation, you might (if you use Saxon PE/EE) want to look into the various extensions Saxon offers for processing maps https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/saxon/with-pedigree.html, https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/saxon/pedigree.html. There are also some papers and/or blogs entries by Michael Kay/Saxonica on that, I think.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the match, the issue is that the intermediary structure is an element with nested stuff, but it looks like I;d have to change the whole thing to a map in order to embed this map inside it?

Comment: You can't have a map or array inside of a node like an element or of a document node. You can have nodes inside of array or of map values.

Comment: ok, so the other issue is then can i serialise this intermediary structure into the output?
I do this quite a lot to debug complex chains?

Comment: actually, i know i can...so ignore me

Comment: Maps/array can be serialized with output method `adaptive` and for certain maps/arrays also as `json`.

Comment: actually, I think i'll do an island of processing based on map/array, then flip it into elements in the pipeline